# Windows CE 6.0 (OEM 5.37) not displayed hourglass cursor

Tags: c#, cursor, windows-ce

I have a problem with displaying the hourglass and custom cursors in Windows CE applications on OEM 5 platform. Question is that the cursor does not display by default, and is displayed only when I click on the screen.
Interestingly, the hourglass cursor spins correctly on OEM 4 platform.
I think, that in OEM 5, UI would updated only by actions outside.
What can be done so that the cursor will update correctly at the screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar issue. Here so far what I know and what solutions you have:

- In some mobile operating systems the wait-cursor is very sensitive. When you activate him twice (without deactivating him) he will not appear again.
- Also there are CE-Devices where a wait-cursor won't show up.
- You could disable all controls when you are processing something
- You can also put a wait-image or a wait-label in the middle of the screen instead of using the wait-cursor.

My colleagues and I spent lots of hours on these buggy wait-cursors under windows ce. Finally we gave up and used this solutions I mentioned.